# Solving an initial value problem for the PDE $u_t + u_x = (x+t) \cos(xt)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is my first time to study PDE in grad level . I have to solve this IVP :

$$
u_t + u_x = (x+t) \cos(xt)  \tag{*}
$$ 
on $\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$.

$$
u(x,0) = \sin(x) \tag{**}
$$ 
on $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \{t=0\}$.

In my class note, I was given a formula to use , and I obtain:

$$
u(x,t) = \sin(x-tb) + 
\int\limits_0^t \left[x-(t-\sigma)b+\sigma\right] 
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) \, d\sigma
$$

where $b$ is a constant.

I don't know what I need to do next. Is this one correct?

Comment: You remember that differentiating $\sin k$ gives $\cos k$? So the first thing to try is what happens if you put $u(x,t)=\sin xt$. That should lead you to a particular solution. The equation is linear, so if you find $u(x,t)$ such that $u_x+u_t=0$ you can add that to the particular solution. You need to juggle to satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: Should that be a $+\sigma$ in the cosine in the integrand?

Comment: The formular u(x,t) above I have is from what you said, it looks like a solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checking if your solution candidate fullfills the PDE $(*)$ and boundary condition $(**)$.

The condition $(**)$ holds.

For the PDE we need to calculate $u_x$ and $u_t$. For calculating $u_t$ we use the [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form_with_variable_limits).
We get
$$
\begin{align}
u_x(x,t) 
&= 
\cos(x-tb) + 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
\int\limits_0^t \left[x-(t-\sigma)b+\sigma\right]
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) \, d\sigma \\
&=
\cos(x-tb) + 
\int\limits_0^t 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
\left[x-(t-\sigma)b+\sigma\right] 
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) \, d\sigma \\
&=
\cos(x-tb) + \\
&\int\limits_0^t 
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) -
\left[x-(t-\sigma)b+\sigma\right]
\sin\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) \sigma 
\, d\sigma
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
u_t(x,t) 
&= 
-b \cos(x-tb) + 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
\int\limits_0^t \left[x-(t-\sigma)b+\sigma\right]
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) \, d\sigma \\
&=
-b \cos(x-tb) + 
\int\limits_0^t 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
\left[x-(t-\sigma)b+\sigma\right] 
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) \, d\sigma + \\
& \left[x-(t-t)b+t\right] 
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-t)b\right]t\right) \frac{dt}{dt} \\
&=
-b\cos(x-tb) + \\
&(-b) \int\limits_0^t 
\cos\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) -
\left[x-(t-\sigma)b+\sigma\right]
\sin\left(\left[x-(t-\sigma)b\right]\sigma\right) \sigma \, d\sigma + \\
& (x+t) \cos(xt)
 \\
&=
-b \, u_x(x,t) + (x+t) \cos(xt)
\end{align}
$$
So, assuming I made no mistake, your candidate solves
$$
u_t(x,t) + b \, u_x(x,t) = (x+t) \cos(xt)
$$
which is your $(*)$ if $b = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Why to learn that *complicated* formula? Will you even remember it when taking your exam? Why not using the *method of characteristics*, which I think it should be firstly taught when learning PDEs. In your case, it reads:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(x+t) \cos{xt}}.  $$

From the first equatlity we have: $\mathrm{d}t - \mathrm{d}x = 0, $ which after integrating yields $x-t=c$, where $c$ is a constant called characteristic. Take now the second equality and put $x$ as a function of $t$ to have:

$$\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\mathrm{du}}{(2t+c) \cos{[(t+c)t}]},$$

whichi is a separable differential equation. Solve the corresponding integral$^*$ and put the constant of integration as a function of $c = x-t$, solve for the given initial condition and you are done!

Cheers!

---

$^*$Note that the argument of the $\sin$ is a primitive of $2t+c$.

Comment: My professor taught that, so I just looked at the note.

Comment: @Peter, yeah, I'm aware. I was just wondering why your teacher did not explain to you this way to solve these problems! You may find your formula just came out of the blue.

Comment: That solution did not fell out of the sky, there is a method for this. I have the name lying on my tongue. Heck what was it?

Comment: mmmm, nothing comes to my mind right now... It must be some *characteristic* or maybe specific method for this kind of problems...

Comment: Hello again! I'm having trouble understanding the last part where the integration factor is a function of $c$. Why/how does this happen. I see how it works, but not really understanding it

Comment: I think the particular solution might be obtained using [Duhamel's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle).

Comment: @TylerHG. Take a look at the example at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example. You can always equate the Lagrange-Charpit equations to some $d\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an auxiliar variable.

Comment: @mvw : Yes Duhamel 's principle. My professor proved the method in class for general case, and gave out the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=1$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=s+x_0=t+x_0$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=(x+t)\cos xt=(2s+x_0)\cos((s+x_0)s)$ , letting $u(0)=f(x_0)$ , we have $u(x,t)=f(x_0)+\int_0^s(2\sigma+x_0)\cos((\sigma+x_0)\sigma)~d\sigma=f(x-t)+\int_0^t(2\sigma+x-t)\cos((\sigma+x-t)\sigma)~d\sigma$

$u(x,0)=\sin x$ :

$f(x)=\sin x$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\sin(x-t)+\int_0^t(2\sigma+x-t)\cos((\sigma+x-t)\sigma)~d\sigma$